# git: branches disappearing after reset

Tags: git, branch, reset

Here's what I did:

I merged the `kernel_common/android-3.0` into my main [local branch](http://github.com/android/kernel_common/tree/android-3.0).

Then I wanted to reset to Linux 3.0.13, so I looked into the history and found [this](https://github.com/android/kernel_common/commits/android-3.0?page=63)

Problem is, the Android commits appear as untracked changes when resetting (aka. I loose all the commits).

[image]

**See the image above, when I reset to a yellow commit I "loose" the blue ones, and vice-versa.**

Comment: What did you do to "reset" to the other branch? `git reset` is not the right command, use `git checkout` instead.

Comment: Did you use `--hard` when you reset? If yes, then you will lose the commits. What are the branches in your local repo? If you want the changes in `Linux 3.0.13` on your local mainline branch then switch to your local mainline branch and run `git rebase <name-of-the-branch-that-has-Linux 3.0.13>`

Comment: @Koraktor Which other branch? I only have the remote and my local branch.

Comment: @yasouer Good call on the --hard switch, I'll try git rebase.

Comment: @user2037879: Before you try `git rebase`, please read and understand it from here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is perfectly correct that way.

The yellow commits do not contain the blue one and vice versa.

A reset just makes you branch pointing to the new commit, i.e. it will contain only the code at that point in time and does not know anything about a later merge.

If you want to have a new state combining a blue state with a yellow one, just merge those commits:

```
git checkout -b mybranch $blue_SHA1
git merge $yellow_SHA1
```

Comment: The problem is ALL the Android commits even the previously-merged ones disappear, all Android bits disappear in fact...

Comment: A commit contains its whole history including all merges. What makes you think that something disappeared there?

Comment: All android code shows up as untracked files (commits disappear) when I reset to the Linux patch (gregkh) commit, the contrary happens when I reset to Android commit...

Comment: EDIT: no it doesn't disappear but it appears as untracked changes

Comment: Yes, that is the point of reset. Reset tells git to forget everything and reset you to the code at the given time. everything not merged at that time will be gone. (But unless you specify `--hard` it will remain uncommitted in your working copy.) Please rethink, what you want to achieve. Most probably you do not want to reset things. (You probably simply want to merge some android commit into the correct linux commit as shown in this solution.)

Comment: See this paste: http://paste2.org/p/2823971 After resetting when I type "git status" I get all Android code as untracked files / modified files...

Comment: So what should I do here? - Thanks for your help BTW

Comment: @user2037879: git is listing all the android code as untracked because you have run `git reset <commit-id-of-Linux-3.0.13>`. So the `HEAD` is now pointing to the Linux-3.0.13 commit. And all commits made after that are now marked untracked/modified.

Comment: @user2037879: Please read here to understand about Git branch management: http://git-scm.com/book/th/Git-Branching-Branch-Management

Comment: Yes but what I'm saying is that even the Android code from BEFORE gets untracked... because the tree on the Linux patches don't contain Android stuff and vice versa... :s

Comment: e.g here: https://github.com/android/kernel_common/tree/dc1b6340394ef744e210247ab786df66639f5a33/drivers/usb/gadget there is android.c and not here https://github.com/android/kernel_common/tree/d986a8dbfd7358bfbda116650c4caf8a3b90d865/drivers/usb/gadget

Comment: Yes it will, because by running `git reset` you have adjusted the `HEAD` to point to a commit that was in "past". So any commit done after that will become untracked/modified.

Comment: So how can I reset to 3.0.13 while keeping Android code? -- thanks for the help I appreciate it

Comment: EDIT: o shall I understand that this Linux code is from before and that all Android code is applied on top of it (aka. on top of 3.0.58)? Means that it doesn't follow the order that is on Github history?

Comment: @user2037879: My suggestion to you is this: read the pointers on Git branch management, git rebase and git reset. I think you are trying to use git without understanding how it works.

Answer (score -1):

I finally got it: did a `git reset` to the Android commit then merged the Linux commit.

Thanks!